# Convert The input from EditText to TextView

Tags: android

can you help display the input taking from the use and then display it as textView in android. In fact I am making an android app and I collect the input from the user trough the EditText, then when collecting it I would like to display it as a `textView` instead. Tank you. I have tried this:

```
private EditText = mEditText;
private TextView = mTextView;

String name = EditText.getString.getText().toString().trim(); //To collect
```

he user's input

then I used `TextView.setText(name); //the past the string into TextView`

Thank you
then it keep crashing my program

Comment: `please do post your logcat` tank you !

Comment: I got you thank to remind for that

Answer (score 1):

you need first declare your editText & TextView in your onCreate method like this

```
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);

TextView mTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
```

after that you can get what is inside your EditText like this

```
String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
```

and place it inside your textview like

```
mTextView.setText(text);
```

it should work

> Important Note: If you are doing it before the setContentView() method
>   call, then the values will be null.